# How to check if YITH Woocommerce Wishlist is activated in theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a theme with yith woocommerce wishlist which has the following:

`if( ! function_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ){
    function check_yith_enable_or_disable(){
        echo do_shortcode( "[yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist]" );
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'check_yith_enable_or_disable', 10 );
}`

However this breaks the site if the yith woocommerce wishlist plugin is not activated. How can I check if the yith woocommerce wishlist plugin is activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used [is_plugin_active()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active) to check plugin is active or not

> Used Of `is_plugin_active()`

**In the Admin Area:**

```
<?php is_plugin_active($plugin) ?>
```

**In the front end, in a theme, etc...**

```
<?php include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' ); ?>
<?php $plugin='plugin-directory/plugin-file.php'; ?>
<?php is_plugin_active($plugin) ?>
```

**Return Values**

True if plugin is activated, else false.

> For YITH WooCommerce Wishlist in front End

```
 <?php include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' ); ?>
 <?php $plugin='yith-woocommerce-wishlist/init.php'; ?>
 <?php if(is_plugin_active($plugin)){
          //plugin is activated
        }else{
          //plugin is not activated
        } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this use function

```
<?php include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' ); ?>
<?php is_plugin_active($plugin) ?>
```

or more detail check https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active

Answer (score 1):

WordPress includes a function called **`<?php is_plugin_active() ?>`** that allows you to check if the specified plugin is active.

The **is_plugin_active()** can be used like this -

```
<?php
    if( is_plugin_active( 'plugin-folder/main-plugin-file.php' ) )
    {
        // Plugin is active
    }  ?>
```

To check **yith woocommerce wishlist** plugin is activation use this code -

```
<?php if(is_plugin_active('yith-woocommerce-wishlist/init.php'))
      {
           //plugin is activated 
            echo 'Plugin is Activated';
      }
      else
      {
          //plugin is not activated
            echo 'Plugin is not activated';
      } ?>
```

> for reference check-
>
> [Function Reference/is plugin active](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active)
>
> [Checking dependent plugin is active](https://pippinsplugins.com/checking-dependent-plugin-active/)

Comment: Yes, i must insert
`<?php include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' ); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

One of these should work fine;

For checking free version only:

```php
if( class_exists( 'YITH_WCWL_Privacy' ) )
    {
        // YITH Woocommerce Wishlist plugin is active
    }
```

For checking premium version only:

```php
if( class_exists( 'YITH_WCWL_Premium' ) )
    {
        // YITH Woocommerce Wishlist Premium plugin is active
    }
```

For checking any of them is active:

```php
if( class_exists( 'YITH_WCWL' ) )
    {
        // YITH Woocommerce Wishlist (free or premium) plugin is active
    }
```